# Does Spring closes the DataSource when context get destroyed

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am using an embedded DBCP1.3 DataSource in Spring Batch. The batch is packaged inside an EAR and deployed in WAS7 server (But it is not an AppClient). The job is scheduled using a Unix script.

**DataSource Configurations:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="****"/>
    <property name="username" value="***"/>
    <property name="password" value="****"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Once the job is completed I am closing the the **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** spring context explicitly inside a finally block by calling **context.close()**

Now my question is once the job is completed the DataSource get close automatically and releases all the connection created for the database?

**[EDIT]:**
After running the application debug mode I can see it does close the DataSource

```
2016-05-31 11:00:56 DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:302 - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
```

Comment: Check out AbstractApplicationContext.doClose() it unregisters managed beans, sends out an context closed event (to allow clean up for listeners), destroys all beans and all bean factories... so short answer is "yes".

Comment: yes it destroys all beans. ClassPathXmlApplicationContext eventually  extends AbstractApplicationContext which has this close() method, which uses doClose() , you can read the doc or see its implementation which actually destroys all singleton (default scope) beans that were created.

Comment: Thanks Natan & Surya. After running my application in DEBUG mode I can see it does close the DataSource. Edited my questions.